# Insert Wordpress title into html with php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I know this a simple question and I will probably get lambasted for it but I can not get this to work.

Currently the title prints before the h2 and the h2 is empty.

```
echo '<h2 class="profile-title">' . the_title() . '</h2>';
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd suspect `the_title` to call echo internally instead of returning the title. try `echo "<h2>" ; the_title() ; echo "</h2>";` to verify and then hit the developer of said function in their vulnerable parts until they a) fix it and b) give it a better name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get_the_title()`. Standard rule in Wordpress: `the_whatever()` does OUTPUT immediately, while `get_the_whatever()` returns instead. So your `the_title()` outputs the title immediately, returns nothing, and then the rest of the echo kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

`the_title()` is use to print the title and you are printing it over and over by using `echo`. To print the title inside `<h2>` tag use it as :
`echo '<h2 class="profile-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';`

Answer (score 0):

[`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) prints out the value by default.

You can return the value so you can use it in `echo` or `print` statements by passing `true` as the third argument, like this

```
echo '<h2 class="profile-title">' . the_title(null,null,true) . '</h2>';
```

or you can use the first and second parameters, `before` and `after` to build the title as you wish

```
the_title('<h2 class="profile-title">','</h2>');
```

or, if you still want to print it yourself

```
echo the_title('<h2 class="profile-title">','</h2>',true);
```